# Martian packets after connecting with openvpn client

Tags: iptables, routing, openvpn

**Background:**

I connect to a server via an openvpn client (v2.4.4) from the command line from behind a residential router running OpenWRT.

Lately, I've been seeing the following in my syslog:

```
Aug  8 17:16:28 Deluxe kernel: [12972.603549] IPv4: martian source 192.168.1.100 from 34.210.182.212, on dev eno1
Aug  8 17:16:28 Deluxe kernel: [12972.603572] ll header: 00000000: d0 17 c2 ac 64 4b c4 e9 84 48 79 32 08 00        ....dK...Hy2..
Aug  8 17:16:28 Deluxe kernel: [12972.910801] IPv4: martian source 192.168.1.100 from 34.210.182.212, on dev eno1
Aug  8 17:16:28 Deluxe kernel: [12972.910822] ll header: 00000000: d0 17 c2 ac 64 4b c4 e9 84 48 79 32 08 00        ....dK...Hy2..
Aug  8 17:16:28 Deluxe kernel: [12973.230932] IPv4: martian source 192.168.1.100 from 34.210.182.212, on dev eno1
Aug  8 17:16:28 Deluxe kernel: [12973.230953] ll header: 00000000: d0 17 c2 ac 64 4b c4 e9 84 48 79 32 08 00        ....dK...Hy2..
```

The first MAC address in the `ll header` line is my NIC, the second is an ethernet interface on the router.

My route table looks like this before connecting:

```
[2020-08-08 ☱ 18:35 ☴]$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table                                                        
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface  
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno1   
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1
```

And it looks like this after shortly after connecting:

```
[2020-08-08 ☱ 18:35 ☴]$ route -n                                                
Kernel IP routing table                                                             
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface       
0.0.0.0         10.25.40.1      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0        
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno1        
10.25.40.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0        
128.0.0.0       10.25.40.1      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0        
185.228.19.148  192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eno1        
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1
```

The host IP listed second from the bottom is the VPN gateway. The `tun0` adapter is configured like so: `inet 10.25.40.244  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.25.40.244`

After three to five minutes, martian traffic will die down and appear infrequently.

I've tested connecting via `openvpn` without the router in place (connecting directly to my modem) and the same occurs.

I'm going out on a limb here, but it seems like, when there's an abrupt change in routing (as occurs with a user-initiated VPN connection) established/related connections persist and are dropped as invalid. Over time, these connections die off.

**Questions:**

1. Is my understanding of the cause of the martian packets correct?
2. If I want to avoid dropping these packets, how can I do so? For example, could I use the `nat` or `mangle` tables in `iptables` to direct these packets to the `tun` interface?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your understanding is correct.
2. In my case I simply stopped logging such packets. Even if it's an attack it won't work because routing will prevent it from ever succeeding:

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 0
```